# Change a character column to numeric in a data frame

Tags: r, numeric

I want to change a column from a dataframe from character to numeric.
My data frame was a .txt file with 12 columns and 1000 rows.
When I passed the .txt file to R, one of my columns is now character.
I tried to use

```
as.numeric(my_data$iw)
```

But I get a "Warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

Here is the data frame structure:

```
data.frame':   1000 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ im : num  0 15396 16537 20252 17967 ...
 $ iw : chr  "20064.97" "7397.191" "18380.77" "14042.25" ...
 $ r  : num  5984 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ am : num  0 42 33 38 24 62 27 38 0 29 ...
 $ af : num  38 30 28 38 39 42 18 33 24 35 ...
 $ a1c: num  0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ a2c: num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ a3c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ a4c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ a5c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ a6c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ a7c: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

May I change it with `gsub`?

```
structure(list(im = c(0, 15395.61, 16536.74, 20251.87, 17967.04, 
12686.43, 16833.22, 16919.34, 0, 20515.88, 17991.9, 15528.29, 
16683.96, 14485.19, 17957.98, 19923.31, 13526.9, 16516.68, 16337.52, 
12904.97, 17418.99, 12419.21, 14561.9, 12309.77, 21138.87, 0, 
17315.74, 17762.09, 12678.82, 13883.37, 11140.66, 16502.91, 18293.78, 
12533.36, 16536.61, 4336.741, 22449.17, 16532.1, 0, 15905.14, 
0, 8542.03, 12589.29, 15154.76, 15441.59, 18575.05, 15915.47, 
0, 15085.51, 16597.42, 15358.47, 22480.95, 10555.28, 21771.2, 
22863.56, 15937.55, 12230.58, 17814.67, 7972.471, 10286.75, 15335.8, 
10762.59, 18583.2, 12167.99, 21723.37, 15670.79, 13045.83, 13305.73, 
14305.99, 10353.15, 4504.009, 10157.7, 15967.28, 23640.21, 15053.78, 
21404.11, 8509.353, 15693.39, 9009.99, 17249.29, 9115.844, 16057.39, 
14069.93, 0, 0, 16840.09, 0, 15289.29, 12223.93, 13048.58, 18524.13, 
14344.22, 20658.66, 0, 0, 13984.69, 21636.72, 13969.12, 12919.83, 
13214.16, 17066.98, 20060.25, 11414.15, 12907.53, 11289.97, 17600.97, 
14741.77, 12089.57, 13603.85, 9330.662, 0, 16191.81, 12029.75, 
12666.29, 8138.166, 10636.2, 22570.1, 12833.66, 12585.56, 20197.42, 
12621.56, 19021.65, 9948.49, 25772.41, 15102.54, 19225.57, 11188.96, 
11707.66, 9766.824, 16082.82, 17693.2......
```

To read in the .txt file, I wrote:

```
my_data <- read.table("project.txt", header=TRUE);
```

Comment: check `unique(my_data$iw)` to confirm that values are actually numeric. The warning message indicates that some values cannot be converted to numeric values so they are converted to NAs. The strategy to resolve this depends on what you want to do with the non-numeric values.

Comment: Hi marianthi! Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?. It is really important that you include a sample of your data: you may use [`dput()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) on your data to do that. Also, please include the code that you have used to load the data

Comment: they are not numeric.They are character. I want to change them in order to use them in function. So they must not be character because my function will not work..

Answer (score 1):

As some comments already said, this is because either there are some rows which cannot be coerced to numeric. An unsuitable description of missing data or maybe a comma to denote decimals as in

```
expl <- read.table(text = "1.0  2.0  2,3
                           2.0  2.1  2.5
                           .    2.2  2.1")
str(expl)
```

which leads to

```
> str(expl)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "1.0" "2.0" "."
 $ V2: num  2 2.1 2.2
 $ V3: chr  "2,3" "2.5" "2.1"
```

for the reasons stated above.

It is not always easy to find the culprid in 1000 lines, but something like this may help:

```
> which(is.na(as.numeric(expl$V1)))
[1] 3
```

This will provide you with the row numbers that produce `NA` in conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much! I find the culprid and  delete this row.